# How to check my computer has SATA III or SATA II?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, motherboard, sata

I brought a SSD last week that supports SATA III. I wish to connect it to my PC but I have no idea whether my PC has SATA II or SATA III. I can provide any details or screenshots if needed.

**Motherboard**:  ASUS M5A78L-M/USB3
**Chipset**: AMD 780G
**Processor**: AMD FX6100
**OS**: Windows 8.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your motherboard only supports SATA II.

You can find this out by doing a simple Google Search for the motherboard and following the link to the [specification page on the ASUS website](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/M5A78LMUSB3/specifications/). It ways you have "6 x SATA 3Gb/s port(s)" and SATA 3Gb/s is SATA II. ([SATA differences](http://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/8142/~/difference-between-sata-i,-sata-ii-and-sata-iii))

Comment: Of course, your SSD will work on a SATA II port. Just not as fast as it would on a SATA III port.